# Route config "component" for path: / cannot be a string id

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am building routes into my website using `vue-router`, I am attempting to setup my route file the same way [coreui does it](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/blob/master/src/router/index.js). I am currently receiving the error "[vue-router] route config `component" for path: / cannot be a string id. Use an actual component instead`.

./src/router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

// Containers
const DefaultContainer = '../containers/DefaultContainer'; 

// Componenets
// const Navbar = '../components/Navbar';

// Views
const Home = '../views/Home';
const PageNotFound = '../views/404';

// Routes
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router ({
mode: 'hash',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/home',
        name: 'Home | Portfolio | Tom Dickson',
        component: DefaultContainer,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                name: 'Home | Portfolio | Tom Dickson',
                component: Home
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: PageNotFound
    }
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Came back to it and was right in front of me:

**Changed**

`// Containers
const DefaultContainer = '../containers/DefaultContainer';`

**To**

`// Containers
const DefaultContainer = () => import('../containers/DefaultContainer');`

Then updated the rest of my views...